# Azure DevOps Extension - Set ReadOnly Field on Work Item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I have an Azure DevOps Extension that I need to update a ReadOnly Custom Work Item field.

The Custom Field is being set to ReadOnly via a Process Rule.

I realize I can do something like this and bypass the rule via the full API itself:

```
fetch('https://dev.azure.com/aherrick/_apis/wit/workitems/1?api-version=7.0&bypassRules=true', {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
                "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "PAT")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify([{
                "op": "add",
                "path": "/fields/Custom.MyField",
                "value": "100"
            }])
        });
```

However, I don't want to have to embed a PAT in my Azure DevOps Extension. I've tried something like this using the VSS Work Item Client:

```
        var document = [{
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/Custom.MyField",
            "value": "10001"
        }];

        witClient.updateWorkItem(document, 1)
            .then(function (response) {

                console.log(response);

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);

            });
```

However, how do I Bypass Rules using the built in VSS Work Item Client? Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What I've come up with seems to work but is a total hack. Essentially I'm using a hidden custom "backing field" that when set to a value (via a rule) my proper custom field is set to read only.

So in code, I force the backing field and remove it's value (thus removing read only from my proper custom field), actually update my custom field, then reset the backing field. :(

There has to be a cleaner way?